# How do we call Suitelet from RESTlet by using SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: netsuite

Can anybody explain How do we call `Suiteletfrom RESTlet`?

The Code Snippet is:

```
serverResponse.sendredirect({
type: 'SUITLET',
identifier: 'customscript_sample_rl_cals_sl',
id: 'customdeploy_sample_rl_cals_sl'
});
```

But I am not able to find out the serverResponse in RESTlet while using https module, can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to call a Suitelet within a RESTlet. Your Suitelet must be available without login. In this example the https module variable is referred as HTTPSMODULE:

```
var myRequest = {};
myRequest.headers = {};
myRequest.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0";
myRequest.url = 'https://XXXXXXXXX'; //Suitelet External URL
var myResponse = HTTPSMODULE.get(myRequest);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply,Can you also please let me know how do i pass the parameter from RESTlet to SUITElet, actually My problem is with MAP Reduce script, when i was call the MAP / Reduce script from RESTlet it says like insufficient permission even i am using Administrator role. But where as in DEMO(TEST) account it does work without any issue, if you know the solution , can you please help on this?

Comment: i am getting the issue in Sandbox account,where as in Demo account it is working fine

Comment: I have passed wrong role through Suitelet ,Now it is working fine,Thanks for your update